# Display Corresponding Item data value in a modal for a header data value displayed as table in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am developing an angular application where I receive my data from the server in which I put only header data in tables and for coressponding header data I had created a button in table and when user click the button the corresponding item data need to be displayed in the Boostrap Modal.

Here I face a problem where in modal I receive only the first data for all the corresponding rows.

My appcomponent.html  file

```
<table class="table"  > 
    <thead class="table-info"> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Customer Number</th>
            <th>Sales Doc Number</th>  
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name of Person </th>      
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let val of user | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index" class="shaded">
            <td>{{val.KUNNR}}</td>
            <td>{{val.VBELN}}</td> 
            <td>{{val.ERDAT}}</td> 
            <td>{{val.ERNAM}}</td>
            <td>
                <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" > <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-white-400"></i></button>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"> Customer Inquiry </h4>
                               </div>
                               <div class="modal-body">
                                  <td>Material Number: {{val.MATNR}}</td>
                                  <br/>
                                   <td>Material Date: {{val.MATWA}}</td>
                                   <br/>
                                   <td>Net Value in Document Currency: {{val.NETWR}}</td>
                                   <br/>
                                   <td>Short Text: {{val.ARKTX}}</td>
                               </div>
                               <div class="modal-footer">
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </td>         
        </tr>
```

My response Received from server contain both the header data value and item value

```
0:
KUNNR: ["0000100000"]
VBELN: ["0010000023"]
ERDAT: ["2015-07-02"]
ERNAM: ["MM_DEMO_BS"]
MATNR: ["F126"]
MATWA: ["F126"]
NETWR: ["1200.00"]
ARKTX: ["coco palm chips"]

1:
KUNNR: ["0000100000"]
VBELN: ["0010000024"]
ERDAT: ["2015-07-02"]
ERNAM: ["MM_DEMO_BS"]
MATNR: ["F125"]
MATWA: ["F125"]
NETWR: ["1200.00"]
ARKTX: ["coconut chips"]

2:
KUNNR: ["0000100000"]
VBELN: ["0010000025"]
ERDAT: ["2015-07-02"]
ERNAM: ["MM_DEMO_BS"]
MATNR: ["F125"]
MATWA: ["F125"]
NETWR: ["1200.00"]
ARKTX: ["coco coconut chips"]

3:
KUNNR: ["0000100000"]
VBELN: ["0010000022"]
ERDAT: ["2015-07-02"]
ERNAM: ["MM_DEMO_BS"]
MATNR: ["F125"]
MATWA: ["F125"]
NETWR: ["1200.00"]
ARKTX: ["coco palm coconut chips"]
```

I have 4 arrays of data,The first 4 fields KUNNR, VBELN, ERDAT, ERNAM need to displayed in a table along with a button. And then on clicking the button for the respecting remaining 3 fields MATNR, MATWA, NETWR, ARKTX need to be displayed in a modal for the corresponding rows. I had displayed the data perfectly witha button but on clicking the button I am getting only the first item data of array O get populating in all of the rows on clicking a button.
But in my code, I am getting header table displaying correctly, but on a button click, I am getting only the first item data for all rows. How can I resolve it Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to show all row / items of array in bootstrap modal.
Follow these steps:

- remove modal section from table / array.
- make a separate section for modal and embed *ngfor array here.

  Customer Number
           Sales Doc Number  
           Date
           Name of Person       
       
   
       
           {{val.KUNNR}}
           {{val.VBELN}} 
           {{val.ERDAT}} 
           {{val.ERNAM}}

  ```
           <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <!-- Modal content-->
                   <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                           <h4 class="modal-title"> Customer Inquiry </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let val of user | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
                             <td>Material Number: {{val.MATNR}}</td>
                             <br/>
                              <td>Material Date: {{val.MATWA}}</td>
                              <br/>
                              <td>Net Value in Document Currency: {{val.NETWR}}</td>
                              <br/>
                              <td>Short Text: {{val.ARKTX}}</td>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
  ```

Comment: It is displaying all the item details in the modal. But I want the corresponding item data in modal wrt to their header data. For Example, I want 0  array item data on clicking button on the first row of table similarly i want the 1 st array item data in modal when i click the 1st row of my header table. Thanks for this code .

Comment: I tried doing but I am not able do it Can you help me to figure where I am going wrong

Comment: assign single item value on click method and use this in modal. i.e use singleItem; variable in .ts file, assign value to singleItem (click)="singleItem=item" and use this singleItem instead of embed whole array.